# Mapping Lambda Expressions that return Booleans

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

I'm trying to map a String to Lambda Expressions. The expressions take a variable(map) and either return false or run a getOrDefault on the given map variable. But for some reason, I am getting errors.

```
Map<String, Runnable> order_function = new HashMap<>();
order_function.put("AlternativesValues", (Map x) -> { return false; });
order_function.put("AlternativesConstituent", (Map x) -> { x.getOrDefault("orderCloseCons", false); });
```

Comment: Why do you think, `Runnable` is a suitable interface for a function that will need a `Map` as input and return a `boolean`?

Comment: @Holger I'm still quite new to Java so I'm not sure which one is more suitable, sorry :(

Comment: You will note when you actually try to *invoke* the functional method. Does [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html#run--) look suitable for your task?

Comment: @Holger I saw a similar implementation online that used Runnable so I went with it. Would using Function be more suitable?

Comment: You may go through [these interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) and pick the most suitable. The problem is that “trying to map a String to Lambda Expressions” is not an actual, useful programming problem. When you start with whatever you need the map for, you’ll soon recognize what is useful and what is not. Whether the interface is implemented via lambda expressions or ordinary classes, is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) doesn't return anything. If you expand the lambda to the anonymous class implementation, you will see the `void` is the return type:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // implementation
    }
};
```

This is in conflict with your lambda> `(Map x) -> { return false; }`.

Since you need an expression which *takes* a `Map` and *returns* a `boolean`, then you need [`Predicate<Map<? ,Boolean>>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) (keep the wildcard `?` or replace it with whatever is needed):

```
Map<String, Predicate<Map<? ,Boolean>>> order_function = new HashMap<>();
order_function.put("AlternativesValues", x -> false);
order_function.put("AlternativesConstituent", map -> map.getOrDefault("orderCloseCons", false));
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you wanted to use `Function` instead of `Runnable`:

```
Map<String, Function<Map<String, Boolean>, Boolean>> order_function = new HashMap<>();
order_function.put("AlternativesValues", x -> false);
order_function.put("AlternativesConstituent", map -> map.getOrDefault("orderCloseCons", false));

//...
boolean alternativesValues = order_function.get("AlternativesValues").apply(someMap);
```

Comment: Or `Map<String, Predicate<Map<String, Boolean>>`, to preclude `null` results…

Answer (score 0):

If they mean to be constants, you can use `enum` like below.

```
enum OrderFunctions {
    ALTERNATIVES_VALUES("AlternativesValues", map -> false),
    ALTERNATIVES_CONSTITUENT("AlternativesConstituent", map -> map.getOrDefault("orderCloseCons", false));

    private final String name;
    private final Function<Map<String, Boolean>, Boolean> orderFunction;

    OrderFunctions(String name, Function<Map<String, Boolean>, Boolean> orderFunction) {
        this.name = name;
        this.orderFunction = orderFunction;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Function<Map<String, Boolean>, Boolean> getOrderFunction() {
        return orderFunction;
    }

}
```

and you can use it like below.

```
OrderFunctions.ALTERNATIVES_CONSTITUENT.getOrderFunction().apply(someMap);
```